# unable to see spring logging with log4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging

I have log4j configured in my j2ee application, 

I am able to see log messages from my classes fine - I am unable to see messages from the spring framework (to debug @RequestMapping issues)

 I am using latest spring (4.0) and log4j (1.2.17)

 This is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.H=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.H.File=c:/tmp/AppLog.html
log4j.appender.H.MaxFileSize=4000KB
log4j.appender.H.Append=false
log4j.appender.H.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.H.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout

log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, H
```

I added this to allow Spring to log,

 but no output from spring.....

```
##Spring Framework
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j.properties file make the following changes:

From:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

To:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Comment: Add only `log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG` and please try.